# What's inside Istio's base component

Tags: kubernetes, devops, istio, servicemesh

I'm wondering what's inside Istio's base component. There is a configuration in Istio operator - only 2 settings - enable/disable and k8s. I looked through the documentation and there is no list of components included in the "base". Is that IstioD or something else?

Comment: The components are no longer split, it's a single pod now, unless you could envoy containers.

Comment: @jordanm there is no such pod like "base" in istio-system or kube-system

Comment: It's istiod, see: https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/

Comment: Theoretically, it is. But there is no mention in docs what is "base". In the link, there are no mentions too

Answer (score 0):

When I install `IstioOperator` using below yaml, it only installs istio's CRD resources.

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: empty
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
```

You can install above IstioOperator using `istiosctl`

```bash
istioctl install -f base-only-istio-op.yaml
```